# Swift: SKStoreReviewController - how often can it be called?

Tags: ios, storekit, skstorereviewcontroller

The documentation says that an app can ask a User three times per year via SKSToreReviewController to place a rating.

Most suggest to save a variable in UserDefaults and call the function after a couple of uses. What happens if you call the function more than three times per year? Will the App Store just ignore the calls and after a year asks for a rating again or will you get some kind of error?

And what happens if the app has been updated (ie. a jump from version 1.0 to version 2.0)? Will the 3 requests be reset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, you choose the appropriate time to display the alert, but the system will decide whether to actually show the alert or not. So don't worry about "over-calling" as long as you don't call it as a response to user interaction.

> Although you should call this method when it makes sense in the user experience flow of your app, **the actual display of a rating/review request view is governed by App Store policy**. **Because this method may or may not present an alert**, it's not appropriate to call it in response to a button tap or other user action.

Highlight mine.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview

As for your second question, the only reference I can find regarding how many times it might be displayed is "3 times per year". It doesn't mention 3 times per app version or update. Use this API wisely.

Comment: Hi Andy...how you have written a logic...You will call this storekit 4 times per year...or do you have any other logic.

Comment: @prabakaraniOS I personally call the method every 7 days. The framework will decide to show the alert or not.

Comment: So, from our end no need to write any logic. right?.  It will automatically handle review pop up from apple stokit framework.

Comment: To show the prompt itself, no, you don't need to do anything. The important thing to remember is that you can just tell the framework when you *intend* to show the prompt. If, for example, you intend to show the prompt every 7 days, you need to handle the 7 days part yourself. The prompt itself will show up a max of 3 times, regardless of how many days pass and how many calls to the the request review prompt you do.